# Can a refractometer adequately measure sugar content in fruit pulp?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am trying to measure the sugar content in mango pulp (used for food processing).

Using a hydrometer to measure specific gravity is not adequate because the pulp thickness prevent the hydrometer from adjusting its level as expected. As a work around I am diluting the pulp to a 1:1 ratio of water and mesure the gravity which I then multiply by 2, though strongly doubting this is an accurate methodology.

I am considering measuring the same with a refractometer, reading a proposed methodology suggesting to squeeze the pulp through a fine filter (cheese cloth) and using the extracted liquid to measure sugar content.

So I have few concerns:

1. How much solid is too much so as to skew the measurement with a refractometer?
2. Assuming the extracted liquid is not polluted by solids, how to ascertain this liquid is representative of the sugar content of the pulp (and that solids do not trap more sugar that would be omitted in the measurement)?

Comment: Just a comment: indeed your method of dilution alter the results. You should look at the sugar content of the diluted solution then recalculate back. Also in this case you run into the problem that some sugar is within the pulp anyway. I guess that even big industry evaluate a kind of "average“ or the desired value is set to the accessible part, ie the sugar in the aqueous phase. At least for processing purposes it should be enough. For a value to be put in a dietary info box it might be different and analysis should be required. I guess you can find this in a book for food analysis if you won

Comment: ... won't get an answer here.